# Algorithm for vb text to speech. It is not reading continuously

Tags: razor

Can anyone enhance my code in vb.net??

```
Private Sub btnload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnspeak.Click    
    Dim str As String = Trim(txttext.Text)
    Dim stringfilter As String
    Dim ringpath As String
    Dim words As String()
    Dim wordsingle As String

    If Len(str) = 0 Then
        MsgBox("please enter the text.")
        Exit Sub

    End If

    stringfilter = "*.mp3"
    words = str.Split(New Char() {" "c})

    For Each wordsingle In words
        MsgBox(wordsingle)
        ringpath = "d:\voices\" + wordsingle + ".mp3"
        mpplayer.URL = (ringpath)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be a bit more specific as to what you'd like to achieve.
As it currently stands your post will most likely be flagged and closed since it doesn't confirm with the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).